# time invariance for "Translations" versus "Galilean transformations"

Tags: galilean-relativity, invariants

Why would the time coordinate (t) be NOT invariant under translations, but invariant under Galilean transformations? I thought it should be invariant under both

Here is what I'm tying to understand: 
[image]

Comment: Can you write what happens to $t$ under each of these transformations?

Comment: Could you help / elaborate / point me in the right direction? I wouldn't have asked my question had I known the answer to your question (I'm not saying this in a bitter tone,  this is really how I feel).

Comment: The question you added at the bottom is too vague to answer without knowing exactly how your textbook defines “translations”. The word “translations” can be shorthand for “spatial translations”, “time translations”, or. “spacetime translations”.

Comment: Given the N answer, it is apparently referring to time translations or spacetime translations but not spatial translations.

Comment: @G.Smith Yes that was the problem thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @G.Smith I'm not sure if I should delete this question or if you want to write an answer?

Answer (score 0):

In your [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/500693/galilean-transformation-vs-simple-translation), the answer that you accepted clearly and correctly stated that $t’=t$ for *both* spatial translations and Galilean transformations. So time *is* invariant under both those kinds of transformations.

If you are now asking about *time* translations, well, time shifts by a constant under a time translation so it is obviously not invariant under them.